# Do headless works for Android Automation Tests also?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, headless-ui

I was working on few Android Tests, Just as in web - we have an option for headless browser.

Does it works for Apps also both Android and IOS?

Comment: Set this capability to true to run the Emulator headless when device display is not needed to be visible. false is the default value. isHeadless is also support for iOS, check XCUITest-specific capabilities. so only used for simulators or emulators, not for real devices